# How to add gmail login functionality in django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I want to authenticate a user by allowing him to login through gmail account id in python django. I searched for it excessively but no fruitful results are found on the web. Does any one know how to do this?? I am using pycharm IDE .

Comment: Please tell us about the steps you've performed so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's strange that you don't find anything, there are a lot of packages to achieve this like:

- https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth
- http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: actually I want some good tutorial for this purpose. I am a beginner so these explanations are not pretty clear to me

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to ask for tutorials, is a place to ask specific questions